# Keeping Wifi-Direct Turned on AOSP devices

Tags: android, reflection, wifi, android-source, wifi-direct

My friend and I are developing an app that streams synchronized music between android devices using wifi-direct. Our issue is that while the app works fairly well once phones are connected, it takes some doing to get phones to connect because on all AOSP devices it appears that wifi direct is only turned on upon entering the wifi direct menu (and immediately closed upon exiting). This makes in-application connection rather difficult. We were wondering if there is any way to turn on wifi direct from the code and keep it on (if anyone could refer us to a detailed description of how to do this using Reflection that would be fantastic).

Thanks! Here is our current code:

```
public class Reflector {
static Method turnOnICS;
static Method turnOnJB;
static Method turnOffICS;

public static void turnOnP2P(WifiP2pManager m, Channel c) {
    //Log.v("button", "turnOnP2P");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 14 || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 15) {
        //Log.v("version", "Version is ICS");
        try {
            turnOnICS = WifiP2pManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("enableP2p",WifiP2pManager.Channel.class);
            turnOnICS.setAccessible(true);
            turnOnICS.invoke(m, c);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.v("ics_error", "ICS enableP2p() not found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ics_error", "turnOnICS invocation failure");
        }
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 16 || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 17) {
        //Log.v("version", "Version is JB");
        try {
            turnOnJB = NsdManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setEnabled", boolean.class);
            turnOnJB.setAccessible(true);
            turnOnJB.invoke(NsdManager.class, true);
            //must feed it an nsdmanager, but none exists in wifidirectactivity
            Log.v("nsd", "problem");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.v("jb_error", "JB setEnabled() not found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("jb_error", "turnOnJB invocation failure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void turnOffP2P(WifiP2pManager m, Channel c) {
    //Log.v("button", "turnOffP2P");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 14 || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 15) {
        //Log.v("version", "Version is ICS");
        try {
            turnOffICS = WifiP2pManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("disableP2p", WifiP2pManager.Channel.class);
            turnOffICS.setAccessible(true);
            turnOffICS.invoke(m, c);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.v("ics_error", "ICS disableP2P() not found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ics_error", "turnOffICS invocation failure");
        }
    }
}

public static void printAll(){
    Method[] list = WifiP2pManager.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method m : list){
        Log.v("tag",m.getName());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you found a way to keep Wifi Direct on? I face the same problem that once wifi direct exits, I have to manually go to settings to turn it on.

Comment: No, we never figured it out. Hopefully the android devs have made this functionality more accessible by now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question... it's been a question we've been wrestling with as we add WiFi Direct features to our app.

After looking through the settings on several phones from different manufacturers, and reading pages like [this](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-203900/) and [this](https://www.androidpit.com/what-is-wifi-direct) (which admittedly are not very precise in the details, but it's the best we could find), we've come to the conclusion that there's no need to separately turn on WiFi Direct *per se*: it's enabled whenever WiFi is enabled. So, at most, your app would need to [turn on WiFi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)).

However, WiFi Direct **scanning** (and visibility to being scanned) is what you initiate by going to the WiFi Direct settings page.

Leaving that page may stop the scanning (though 3rd-party [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam&hl=en) [can](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en) [and](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo?autodive=0) [do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estmob.android.sendanywhere&hl=en) initiate their own scanning), but should not disable WiFi Direct. That would make no sense at all... as you say, that would make it difficult (impossible) for apps to use WiFi Direct, but [apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wifi%20direct&c=apps&hl=en) do use it successfully. What did you see that made it seem like WiFi Direct was being disabled when you left that settings page?